# How to remove an ACL from a Mac OS symlink - in C

Tags: c, macos, filesystems

It's a known problem on MacOS that the supplied command line tools (chmod) cannot remove an ACL from a symbolic link: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1440377?start=0&tstart=0

So I thought I'd break out the C compiler and get it done .. before I realised that ACLs hadn't been invented the last time I used C on Unix.

Can anyone say what system calls (MacOS for preference, if this isn't yet a Unix-wide standard) I can draw on to make this happen?

M.

Comment: This was fixed sometime after 10.6.8 and before or in 10.8.3. The command-line chmod in 10.8.3 modifies ACLs on links.

Answer (score 0):

The function `acl_get_link_np(path, ACL_TYPE_EXTENDED)`should let you get the ACLs for a path without following symlinks.

Also, I'd think that `acl_get_link_np(fd, ACL_TYPE_EXTENDED)` should work if you first open the symlink with `open(path, O_NOFOLLOW)`.

To remove all ACLs from a file, you'd use this code:

```
acl_t acl = acl_get_link_np (path, ACL_TYPE_EXTENDED);
if (acl) {
    acl_entry_t entry;
    int res = acl_get_entry (acl, ACL_FIRST_ENTRY, &entry);
    bool didModify = false;
    while (res == 0) {
        res = acl_delete_entry (acl, entry);
        if (res) break;
        didModify = true;
        res = acl_get_entry (acl, ACL_NEXT_ENTRY, &entry);
    }
    if (didModify) {
        int res = acl_set_link_np (path, ACL_TYPE_EXTENDED, acl);
        if (res) {
            NSLog(@"%s – Write ACL: %s", path, strerror(errno));
        }
    }
    acl_free (acl);
}
```